# Obscure a UITextField password with asterisk instead of dots xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am creating an crossplatform app using Xamarin.Forms. In which I want to customize password field with asterisk instead of dots. I am able to do it in Android using renderer but for iOS I don't have any idea.